# sed replace variables while read lines

Tags: variables, loops, sed, while-loop

I'm working on a shell script and i need to change some strings from different lines of a file into a while read statement. The structure need to be like this, because the String_Search and String_result will be calculated on each line.

```
while read line 
do  
   varA="String_Search"   
   resA="String_Result"
   line=`echo $line | sed -e "s/$varA/$resA"`
   echo $line >> outputFile.txt
done < "inputFile.txt"
```

The script doesn't works and its showing to me this error message:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command
```

Anyone Can Help Me?

Thanks to All

Comment: At first sight, the substitution instruction of `sed` is: `s/pattern/replacement/` (note last slash).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to end the substitution pattern by a slash `/`

```
line=`echo $line | sed -e "s/$varA/$resA/"`
```