# While loop to find potential reading frames

Tags: bash, sed, while-loop

I want to create a "while read line" loop that reads the content of my file line by line and execute a series of commands.

The posted code is what I tried so far. However, I am having difficulty running the loop because i get an error message "file name to large." I am new to coding, so I am not even sure if this code would work if the presented problem wasn't an issue in the first place. Also, I would like to know how to input my results from the loop into one file. Thank you for the time.

```
FILE=$(cat RFn2.txt)

while read line

do

sed 's/atg/@atg/g'
sed 's/tag/tag#/g'
sed 's/tga/tga#/g'
sed 's/taa/taa#/g'
perl -lne 'print for /@(.*?)#/g' 

fi

done > $FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed` can be used to do "in place" replacement in the file. i.e. No need to parse line by line. If that works for you then please refer to [sed replace variables while read lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717302/sed-replace-variables-while-read-lines) discussion.

If you need to parse line by line, try below code. Please note that I could not test `perl` part. But it should work if you uncomment the code. Below piece of code will create a new file `RFn2_new.txt`

- `cat $FILE` outputs file content. `|` redirects the output as input to `while` loop.
- For each line, `echo $line` output is redirected to series of `sed` and `perl` commands.
- Each output from `while` loop is redirected to a new file $FILE_NEW

```
FILE=RFn2.txt
NEW_FILE=RFn2_new.txt

cat $FILE | while read -r line

do

echo $line | sed 's/atg/@atg/g' |
                sed 's/tag/tag#/g' |
                sed 's/tga/tga#/g' |
                sed 's/taa/taa#/g' #|
                #perl -lne 'print for /@(.*?)#/g'

done  > $NEW_FILE
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. When I "echo $FILE", my output is "RFn2.txt." It read the name of the file instead of the contents of the file.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Yes echo $FILE will output "RFn2.txt". You don't need to have content in FILE. You are passing file handle to while loop (done < $FILE) and that indirectly reads file content.

Comment: When I present the loop with "FILE=RFn2.txt", I get no output. It is as if the file isn't read.

Comment: Would you please post the content of file `RFn2.txt`?

Comment: @hisholimessadan ... I updated my answer. As tshiono requested, please post minimal content of RFn2.txt which you believe should get printed in file.

Comment: BTW You have asked another question [I want to be able to extract two different sequences from one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58295188/i-want-to-be-able-to-extract-two-different-sequences-from-one-line) which has two answers but you haven't respond to them. The question above looks your own approach without referring to the previous one. You better start with trying the provided answers first.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. in your loop you just need to echo the contents of the line of the file.

```
FILE=RFn2.txt

while read line ; do

echo $line | sed 's/atg/@atg/g'| 
    sed 's/tag/tag#/g'| 
    sed 's/tga/tga#/g' | 
    sed 's/taa/taa#/g' | 
    perl -lne 'print for /@(.*?)#/g')" 

fi

done > $FILE
```

Comment: And how does while loop get RFn2.txt line by line?